# the d3 style fill is being filled in a wierd way

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

Trying to create a line graph with some thousand values who are in the range from 10^-7 to 10^-9, the line graph is being created, but instead of getting filled on x-axis it's getting filled around the hypotenuse.

The issue I think is with data because fitting some other values in the code seems fine.
this is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/43sz9e2d/1/

any help?

html file :

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <svg height=400 width=600></svg>
  <title>
    diff colour area chart
  </title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./diff_area_line_graph.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="diff_area_line_graph.css">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

js file :

```
var data=[
  0.003098344217418779,
  0.003050455340422816,
  0.003003483230367491,
  0.0029574879000276526,
  0.002912526785452867,
  0.0028686546791307594,
  0.0028259236703412974,
  0.0027843830926729696,
  0.002744079478649364,
  0.0027050565213931053,
  0.0026673550432336377,
  0.0026310129711459274,
  0.002596065318888872,
  0.00256254417569515,
  0.00253047870134838,
  0.0024998951274688534,
  0.002470816764815812,
  0.0024432640164022018,
  0.0024172543962071363,
  0.002392802553261877,
  0.0023699203008770396,
  0.002348616650771901,
  0.0023288978518611132,
  0.002310767433449818,
  0.0022942262525850153,
  0.0022792725453091183,
  0.0022659019815607726,
  0.0022541077234683004,
  0.0022438804867823898,
  0.0022352086051969397,
  0.0022280780973101154,
  0.002222472735981723,
  0.0022183741198478295,
  0.002215761746759102,
  0.0022146130889155774,
  0.0022149036694773536,
  0.002216607140438076,
  0.0022196953615558597,
  0.0022241384801445128,
  0.002229905011536446,
  0.0022369619200374486,
  0.0022452747002025143,
  0.0022548074582710172,
  0.0022655229936087897,
  0.0022773828800138536,
  0.0022903475467518186,
  0.0023043763591960504,
  0.002319427698956744,
  0.0023354590433918533,
  0.0023524270444014645,
  0.002370287606415529,
  0.0023889959634929995,
  0.0024085067554581213,
  0.0024287741030070823,
  0.002449751681725264,
  0.002471392794961985,
  0.0024936504455158976,
  0.002516477406090043,
  0.002539826288480973,
  0.002563649611471339,
  0.002587899867399917,
  0.0026125295873871248,
  0.002637491405197819,
  0.002662738119726399,
  0.002688222756092124,
  0.0027138986253349927,
  0.002739719382704612,
  0.002765639084536167,
  0.002791612243708974,
  0.0028175938836840714,
  0.002843539591118028,
  0.0028694055670505344,
  0.002895148676663491,
  0.0029207264976091863,
  0.0029460973669048316,
  0.002971220426390201,
  0.0029960556667444293,
  0.003020563970057162,
  0.003044707150948344,
  0.003068447996229814,
  0.0030917503031008234,
  0.003114578915868368,
  0.0031368997611820855,
  0.0031586798817722526,
  0.003179887468678261,
  0.0032004918919538382,
  0.0032204637298342063,
  0.003239774796349395,
  0.003258398167367057,
  0.0032763082050473505,
  0.0032934805806918124,
  0.0033098922959676476,
  0.0033255217024885098,
  0.003340348519732665,
  0.003354353851279369,
  0.003367520199344506,
  0.0033798314775968052,
  0.0033912730222365245,
  0.003401831601319151,
  0.0034114954223075965,
  0.0034202541378374213,
  0.003428098849680906,
  0.003435022110897216,
  0.003441017926157568,
  0.003446081750236053,
  0.0034502104846587996,
  0.0034534024725062333,
  0.003455657491365507,
  0.0034569767444325604,
  0.0034573628497658504,
  0.0034568198276964343,
  0.0034553530864018973,
  0.003452969405654467,
  0.0034496769187566563,
  0.003445485092680776,
  0.0034404047064317865,
  0.0034344478276560875,
  0.003427627787522027,
  0.0034199591539011277,
  0.0034114577028821827,
  0.0034021403886536497,
  0.0033920253117928983,
  0.0033811316860040165,
  0.0033694798033490304,
  0.0033570909980203943,
  0.003343987608705605,
  0.0033301929395977096,
  0.0033157312201082543,
  0.0033006275633419685,
  0.003284907923395031,
  0.003268599051541288,
  0.0032517284513731044,
  0.0032343243329657624,
  0.0032164155661363798,
  0.0031980316328702376,
  0.003179202578989168,
  0.0031599589651382493,
  0.0031403318171684814,
  0.003120352575994384,
  0.0031000530470065486,
  0.003079465349120054,
  0.003058621863540451,
  0.0030375551823295047,
  0.0030162980568533117,
  0.00299488334619558,
  0.0029733439656188855,
  0.0029517128351565537,
  0.002930022828417493,
  0.002908306721685796,
  0.002886597143396242,
  0.002864926524066018,
  0.0028433270467619477,
  0.0028218305981813872,
  0.002800468720423617,
  0.0027792725635271114,
  0.002758272838846489,
  0.0027374997733411815,
  0.0027169830648460214,
  0.002696751838391975,
  0.00267683460364311,
  0.002657259213513734,
  0.002638052824027268,
  0.0026192418554760646,
  0.002600851954938856,
  0.002582907960209931,
  0.0025654338651915354,
  0.0025484527867981996,
  0.002531986933418974,
  0.0025160575749806876,
  0.002500685014652473,
  0.0024858885622288628,
  0.0024716865092258185,
  0.0024580961057210572,
  0.002445133538967037,
  0.0024328139138019176,
  0.002421151234880811,
  0.00241015839074656,
  0.0023998471397562626,
  0.0023902280978767175,
  0.0023813107283589393,
  0.0023731033332988856,
  0.002365613047088544,
  0.002358845831758557,
  0.0023528064742106367,
  0.002347498585335074,
  0.002342924601005835,
  0.002339085784942825,
  0.002335982233428177,
  0.0023336128818606094,
  0.002331975513129236,
  0.002331066767785519,
  0.002330882155989485,
  0.0023314160712037393,
  0.0023326618056063353,
  0.002334611567191121,
  0.0023372564985217796,
  0.002340586697103494,
  0.002344591237333877,
  0.0023492581939926435,
  0.002354574667227345,
  0.0023605268089904492,
  0.002367099850881042,
  0.0023742781333424947,
  0.002382045136165614,
  0.0023903835102449702,
  0.002399275110534428,
  0.0024087010301462298,
  0.0024186416355364625,
  0.0024290766027182027,
  0.002439984954442278,
  0.002451345098284227,
  0.00246313486557478,
  0.0024753315511100568,
  0.0024879119535765443,
  0.002500852416624961,
  0.0025141288705261603,
  0.0025277168743414375,
  0.002541591658538823,
  0.0025557281679863338,
  0.0025701011052525684,
  0.002584684974144581,
  0.002599454123412588,
  0.002614382790550791,
  0.0026294451456234137,
  0.002644615335044987,
  0.0026598675252438963,
  0.0026751759461383744,
  0.002690514934354304,
  0.002705858976114543,
  0.0027211827497298914,
  0.002736461167622379,
  0.002751669417812187,
  0.0027667830048002267,
  0.0027817777897793114,
  0.002796630030107783,
  0.0028113164179805164,
  0.002825814118233428,
  0.00284010080521889,
  0.002854154698690827,
  0.0028679545986397973,
  0.0028814799190199506,
  0.0028947107203114546,
  0.00290762774086383,
  0.0029202124269675053,
  0.002932446961602952,
  0.002944314291818867,
  0.0029557981546930673,
  0.002966883101832087,
  0.002977554522367839,
  0.002987798664412222,
  0.002997602654933067,
  0.003006954518017523,
  0.0030158431914916765,
  0.0030242585418679894,
  0.0030321913775950343,
  0.0030396334605869157,
  0.003046577516012762,
  0.003053017240329711,
  0.0030589473075459165,
  0.0030643633737032225,
  0.0030692620795723297,
  0.003073641051556485,
  0.003077498900802953,
  0.0030808352205247648,
  0.003083650581538514,
  0.0030859465260272313,
  0.003087725559540625,
  0.003088991141248241,
  0.0030897476724643484,
  0.00309000048346656,
  0.0030897558186334093,
  0.0030890208199292534,
  0.0030878035087680074,
  0.003086112766290274,
  0.00308395831209144,
  0.0030813506814412993,
  0.003078301201038607,
  0.00307482196334681,
  0.003070925799559912,
  0.003066626251250093,
  0.00306193754075122,
  0.003056874540334877,
  0.003051452740237845,
  0.003045688215602231,
  0.00303959759239154,
  0.0030331980123479863,
  0.0030265070970582294,
  0.003019542911196428,
  0.003012323925015147,
  0.0030048689761561016,
  0.0029971972308540547,
  0.0029893281446083807,
  0.002981281422397817,
  0.002973076978514842,
  0.0029647348960968405,
  0.002956275386431778,
  0.0029477187481165715,
  0.002939085326146572,
  0.0029303954710147113,
  0.002921669497898812,
  0.0029129276460153493,
  0.002904190038217599,
  0.0028954766409155924,
  0.0028868072243946174,
  0.0028782013236081806,
  0.0028696781995203703,
  0.002861256801071437,
  0.002852955727839109,
  0.002844793193466776,
  0.002836786989928071,
  0.002828954452695733,
  0.002821312426880729,
  0.0028138772344057246,
  0.002806664642274854,
  0.00279968983199953,
  0.0027929673702377484,
  0.0027865111807018478,
  0.00278033451738718,
  0.002774449939171493,
  0.002768869285832072,
  0.002763603655524879,
  0.0027586633837670127,
  0.002754058023960808,
  0.002749796329494864,
  0.0027458862374541517,
  0.0027423348539681665,
  0.0027391484412228953,
  0.0027363324061590636,
  0.002733891290875829,
  0.002731828764755773,
  0.0027301476183236462,
  0.002728849758847971,
  0.00272793620769123,
  0.002727407099410938,
  0.0027272616826105743,
  0.002727498322535928,
  0.0027281145054090968,
  0.0027291068444890263,
  0.0027304710878442023,
  0.002732202127819842,
  0.002734294012178718,
  0.0027367399568915935,
  0.0027395323605501525,
  0.0027426628203722336,
  0.002746122149766255,
  0.0027499003974187815,
  0.002753986867866372,
  0.0027583701435101478,
  0.0027630381080288226,
  0.0027679779711434383,
  0.002773176294684579,
  0.002778619019910483,
  0.002784291496022268,
  0.0027901785098203213,
  0.002796264316443916,
  0.002802532671134241,
  0.002808966861959218,
  0.0028155497434368794,
  0.0028222637709925343,
  0.0028290910361835793,
  0.002836013302624529,
  0.0028430120425437526,
  0.0028500684739023764,
  0.0028571635980049795,
  0.002864278237530985,
  0.002871393074915066,
  0.0028784886910044397,
  0.002885545603920618,
  0.0028925443080530153,
  0.0028994653131117565,
  0.0029062891831671696,
  0.0029129965756036326,
  0.0029195682799158466,
  0.002925985256276088,
  0.002932228673801621,
  0.0029382799484521994,
  0.002944120780488481,
  0.0029497331914231507,
  0.002955099560397684,
  0.0029602026599189115,
  0.0029650256908908827,
  0.0029695523168789956,
  0.0029737666975448956,
  0.0029776535211923335,
  0.002981198036365907,
  0.0029843860824464697,
  0.0029872041191889393,
  0.002989639255150236,
  0.0029916792749572103,
  0.0029933126653665797,
  0.0029945286400711517,
  0.0029953171632089125,
  0.0029956689715339505,
  0.002995575595210588,
  0.0029950293771946112,
  0.002994023491167968,
  0.0029925519579959074,
  0.0029906096606781203,
  0.002988192357768058,
  0.002985296695237306,
  0.002981920216764506,
  0.0029780613724310853,
  0.002973719525808685,
  0.002968894959425955,
  0.0029635888786050577,
  0.0029578034136609455,
  0.0029515416204591817,
  0.0029448074793307793,
  0.002937605892345186,
  0.002929942678945225,
  0.002921824569950435,
  0.0029132591999378415,
  0.0029042550980118067,
  0.0028948216769771173,
  0.0028849692209320034,
  0.002874708871300228,
  0.002864052611323842,
  0.002853013249040555,
  0.002841604398772023,
  0.0028298404611516235,
  0.0028177366017225363,
  0.002805308728139106,
  0.002792573466006604,
  0.002779548133396539,
  0.0027662507140767093,
  0.0027526998294970825,
  0.0027389147095745136,
  0.002724915162321083,
  0.0027107215423626315,
  0.0026963547183957047,
  0.0026818360396327757,
  0.0026671873012871486,
  0.002652430709150415,
  0.002637588843316774,
  0.002622684621109847,
  0.0026077412592688956,
  0.002592782235452561,
  0.0025778312491193645,
  0.002562912181845268,
  0.002548049057139587,
  0.0025332659998214503,
  0.002518587195019855,
  0.002504036846861113,
  0.0024896391369082023,
  0.0024754181824171275,
  0.0024613979944759466,
  0.0024476024360925983,
  0.002434055180298022,
  0.002420779668331397,
  0.002407799067974553,
  0.0023951362321027415,
  0.002382813657519039,
  0.002370853444139644,
  0.0023592772545972113,
  0.002348106274329219,
  0.0023373611722180615,
  0.002327062061849238,
  0.0023172284634535457,
  0.002307879266598657,
  0.0022990326936948445,
  0.002290706264378887,
  0.0022829167608393874,
  0.002275680194145832,
  0.0022690117716426894,
  0.002262925865468783,
  0.002257435982260932,
  0.0022525547340995697,
  0.002248293810752641,
  0.0022446639532725542,
  0.0022416749289993695,
  0.0022393355080216645,
  0.002237653441144706,
  0.0022366354394136086,
  0.002236287155237142,
  0.0022366131651556775,
  0.002237616954294524,
  0.0022393009025415615,
  0.00224166627248557,
  0.0022447131991491388,
  0.0022484406815473272,
  0.0022528465761005095,
  0.0022579275919269288,
  0.002263679288037568,
  0.0022700960724528377,
  0.0022771712032574644,
  0.002284896791606713,
  0.002293263806693765,
  0.0023022620826846653,
  0.0023118803276238145,
  0.0023221061343093935,
  0.002332925993134573,
  0.0023443253068866523,
  0.0023562884074926045,
  0.00236879857469575,
  0.002381838056644492,
  0.002395388092370261,
  0.0024094289361279828,
  0.002423939883568537,
  0.002438899299708875,
  0.0024542846486615933,
  0.0024700725250819903,
  0.002486238687286821,
  0.0025027580919952503,
  0.0025196049306387743,
  0.0025367526671832784,
  0.0025541740774027858,
  0.0025718412895410084,
  0.0025897258262933725,
  0.002607798648038891,
  0.0026260301972480995,
  0.002644390443990151,
  0.0026628489324592814,
  0.0026813748284380116,
  0.002699936967611842,
  0.0027185039046477254,
  0.0027370439629462416,
  0.0027555252849753432,
  0.002773915883091539,
  0.002792183690752697,
  0.002810296614025081,
  0.002828222583285942,
  0.0028459296050218656,
  0.0028633858136222477,
  0.0028805595230665944,
  0.0028974192784039805,
  0.002913933906922825,
  0.002930072568909263,
  0.0029458048078927182,
  0.0029611006002778746,
  0.002975930404263128,
  0.002990265207946673,
  0.0030040765765227523,
  0.003017336698472204,
  0.0030300184306533287,
  0.0030420953422011705,
  0.0030535417571457037,
  0.0030643327956619924,
  0.003074444413868231,
  0.003083853442090627,
  0.003092537621517395,
  0.003100475639167593,
  0.0031076471611042726,
  0.003114032863825285,
  0.0031196144637691916,
  0.0031243747448779766,
  0.003128297584162696,
  0.003131367975222744,
  0.0031335720496741943,
  0.003134897096447437,
  0.0031353315789193503,
  0.0031348651498502634,
  0.0031334886641011007,
  0.003131194189111326,
  0.0031279750131235212,
  0.0031238256511457534,
  0.0031187418486481977,
  0.0031127205829957734,
  0.0031057600626239047,
  0.0030978597239697484,
  0.0030890202261765207,
  0.0030792434435936975,
  0.003068532456100999,
  0.003056891537289069,
  0.0030443261405346997,
  0.0030308428830132287,
  0.0030164495276954113,
  0.0030011549633805995,
  0.0029849691828223992,
  0.002967903259007178,
  0.00294996931964981,
  0.002931180519974819,
  0.002911551013854725,
  0.0028910959233807427,
  0.0028698313069441712,
  0.00284777412590973,
  0.002824942209964758,
  0.0028013542212306725,
  0.002777029617225223,
  0.0027519886127660097,
  0.0027262521409074252,
  0.0026998418130045115,
  0.0026727798779984163,
  0.002645089181018924,
  0.002616793121400189,
  0.002587915610206046,
  0.002558481027361389,
  0.0025285141784858367,
  0.0024980402515254797,
  0.0024670847732777275,
  0.002435673565903302,
  0.002403832703518221,
  0.0023715884689570928,
  0.002338967310797382,
  0.002305995800732357,
  0.0022727005913783047,
  0.0022391083745992336,
  0.0022052458404297546,
  0.0021711396366740983,
  0.0021368163292563268,
  0.002102302363393732,
  0.0020676240256622055,
  0.0020328074070189955,
  0.0019978783668448143,
  0.0019628624980636495,
  0.0019277850933949448,
  0.0018926711127890533,
  0.0018575451520929953,
  0.001822431412989666,
  0.001787353674249656,
  0.0017523352643308858,
  0.001717399035357215,
  0.0016825673385031936,
  0.0016478620008080916,
  0.0016133043034383533,
  0.0015789149614136584,
  0.0015447141048078367,
  0.001510721261432017,
  0.0014769553410035846,
  0.0014434346208007703,
  0.0014101767327990575,
  0.0013771986522820333,
  0.001344516687915844,
  0.001312146473273079,
  0.0012801029597886862,
  0.0012484004111274084,
  0.001217052398939277,
  0.0011860717999768674,
  0.001155470794545331,
  0.0011252608662536982,
  0.0010954528030335544,
  0.0010660566993889698,
  0.0010370819598395072,
  0.0010085373035162175,
  0.0009804307698688059,
  0.0009527697254405704,
  0.0009255608716663081,
  0.000898810253647143,
  0.000872523269855144,
  0.0008467046827196909,
  0.0008213586300467857,
  0.0007964886372219154,
  0.0007720976301466246,
  0.0007481879488586713,
  0.0007247613617855031,
  0.0007018190805807927,
  0.0006793617754939159,
  0.0006573895912225442,
  0.0006359021631989311,
  0.0006148986342610066,
  0.000594377671660056,
  0.0005743374843575293,
  0.0005547758405643951,
  0.0005356900854774439,
  0.0005170771591680111,
  0.0004989336145797466,
  0.0004812556355933119,
  0.0004640390551171868,
  0.00044727937316516454,
  0.00043097177488255064,
  0.0004151111484845867,
  0.0003996921030721595,
  0.0003847089862914561,
  0.0003701559018058338,
  0.0003560267265498415,
  0.0003423151277369866,
  0.00032901457959454215,
  0.0003161183798003851,
  0.00030361966559855867,
  0.0002915114295719546,
  0.00027978653505221257,
  0.0002684377311486095,
  0.00025745766737939025,
  0.00024683890789063006,
  0.00023657394524934618,
  0.00022665521379916888,
  0.0002170751025684402,
  0.00020782596772213146,
  0.00019890014455045983,
  0.00019028995898851496,
  0.00018198773866261384,
  0.0001739858234604366,
  0.00016627657562330424,
  0.00015885238936019796,
  0.00015170569998431124,
  0.00014482899257406735,
  0.00013821481016160816,
  0.00013185576145279,
  0.00012574452808368454,
  0.00011987387141949035,
  0.00011423663890261295,
  0.00010882576995745931,
  0.00010363430146022826,
  0.00009865537278265362,
  0.0000938822304192749,
  0.00008930823220837494,
  0.00008492685115722855,
  0.00008073167888276199,
  0.00007671642867912283,
  0.0000728749382240056,
  0.00006920117193588204,
  0.00006568922299452901,
  0.00006233331503745405,
  0.000059127803544973336,
  0.00005606717692681184,
  0.00005314605732316719,
  0.00005035920113321183,
  0.00004770149928400165,
  0.00004516797725271938,
  0.00004275379485510474,
  0.000040454245812817735,
  0.00003826475711234397,
  0.00003618088816788652,
  0.000034198329800499275,
  0.000032312903045501934,
  0.00003052055779998092,
  0.000028817371321925253,
  0.000027199546592272164,
  0.000025663410550846423,
  0.0000242054122168745,
  0.000022822120704435795,
  0.000021510223142886566,
  0.0000202665225119536,
  0.000019087935400850824,
  0.000017971489700419525,
  0.00001691432223693785,
  0.000015913676355885315,
  0.00001496689946358681,
  0.000014071440534298036,
  0.000013224847589933063,
  0.00001242476515927355,
  0.000011668931723141874,
  0.00001095517715166556,
  0.000010281420139410831,
  0.000009645665643817674,
  0.000009046002332030452,
  0.000008480600040885558,
  0.000007947707254492636,
  0.000007445648603528832,
  0.000006972822390056683,
  0.0000065276981413762005,
  0.000006108814196130724,
  0.0000057147753256048544,
  0.000005344250392881082,
  0.000004995970052259864,
  0.00000466872449109659,
  0.000004361361215967564,
  0.000004072782884846042,
  0.000003801945186749203,
  0.0000035478547701065,
  0.0000033095672209003674,
  0.0000030861850914407824,
  0.000002876855980455913,
  0.0000026807706650120995,
  0.0000024971612846172263,
  0.000002325299577712047,
  0.000002164495170614263,
  0.000002014093918849715,
  0.0000018734763006834577,
  0.0000017420558625511952,
  0.0000016192777159874831,
  0.0000015046170855515019,
  0.0000013975779071637363,
  0.0000012976914761869784,
  0.0000012045151445127484,
  0.0000011176310658490104,
  0.000001036644988346693,
  9.611850936506414e-7,
  8.909008814150599e-7,
  8.254620982837993e-7,
  7.645577103017318e-7,
  7.078949176947379e-7,
  6.551982109320449e-7,
  6.062084669656222e-7,
  5.606820845267709e-7,
  5.183901573495406e-7,
  4.791176841840743e-7,
  4.4266281445997517e-7,
  4.0883612846017943e-7,
  3.7745995086925334e-7,
  3.4836769656637604e-7,
  3.214032475421487e-7,
  2.964203598296991e-7,
  2.7328209935401775e-7,
  2.5186030561888767e-7,
  2.3203508216795955e-7,
  2.13694312775296e-7,
  1.9673320234085994e-7,
  1.8105384148778802e-7,
  1.6656479388074467e-7,
  1.5318070530797074e-7,
  1.4082193359376209e-7,
  1.294141984328421e-7,
  1.1888825026331956e-7,
  1.091795573205541e-7,
  1.0022801004014188e-7,
  9.197764200429834e-8,
  8.43763666520672e-8,
  7.73757289999229e-8,
  7.093067164538312e-8,
  6.499931435214384e-8,
  5.954274654091494e-8,
  5.452483203551138e-8
]
var svg=d3.select("svg");
// line_x={"20":"red","50":"green"}
 var margin={top:100,bottom:50,left:100,right:0},
   width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
   height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
   g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

x_extent=d3.extent(data,function(d,i){return i})
y_extent=d3.extent(data,function(d,i){return d})

var x= d3.scale.linear()
.range([0,width])
.domain(x_extent)

var y=d3.scale.linear()
.range([height,0])
.domain(y_extent)

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
        .orient("left");

// var vertical_line=d3.svg.line()
// .x(function(d){return d.x})
// .y(function(d){return d.y})

var line=d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d,i){ return x(i)})
.y(function(d,i){return y(d)})

var lg = svg.append("defs").append("linearGradient")
.attr("id", "mygrad")//id of the gradient
.attr("x1", "0%")
.attr("x2", "100%")
// .attr("x3","50%")
// .attr("x4","75%")
.attr("y1", "0%")
.attr("y2", "0%")//since its a vertical linear gradient
;
lg.append("stop")
.attr("offset", "0%")
.style("stop-color", "red")//end in red
.style("stop-opacity", 1)

lg.append("stop")
.attr("offset", "25%")
.style("stop-color", "white")//start in blue
.style("stop-opacity", 1)
// .style("stroke-dasharray", ("3, 3"))

lg.append("stop")
.attr("offset", "75%")
.style("stop-color", "white")//start in blue
.style("stop-opacity", 1)
.style("stroke-dasharray", ("2, 10"))

lg.append("stop")
.attr("offset", "100%")
.style("stop-color", "red")//start in blue
.style("stop-opacity", 1)


g.append("path")
.attr("class","line")
.datum(data)
.attr("d",line)
.style('stroke', 'blue')
// .style("fill", "url(#mygrad)")


// var lowerLimit = d3.quantile(data, 0.18, function(d) {
//     return d.x
// });
//
// svg.append('line')
//     .attr('x1', x(lowerLimit)+margin.left)
//     .attr('y1', height-margin.top)
//     .attr('x2', margin.left+x(lowerLimit))
//     .attr('y2', height+margin.top)
//     .style('stroke', 'brown')
//
//
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left+"," + (height+margin.top) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left+ ","+margin.top+")")
    .call(yAxis);
```

Comment: Do you want a line chart or a area chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want an area chart. The changes are simple, they just tell d3 to close the path along the axis, allowing you to add color to the fill.

https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/43sz9e2d/2/

```
var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d,i){ return x(i)})
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d,i){return y(d)})
```

Comment: Deleted my answer, this is the correct way to do it.